# Seeding a uniformly generated number from (0,1)?

Tags: python, numpy, random

I am using numpy random generator to generate a number from `(0,1)` with

```
np.random.uniform(0,1)
```

I can't find a way to seed a number and still keep it uniformly and randomly chosen from `0` to `1`.

I am also desperately new at coding.

Comment: Do you know what *seeding* means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set the seed for the generator use [`numpy.random.seed`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.seed.html).

Comment: Notice that `value` in `numpy.random.seed(seed=value)` needs to be an integer.

Comment: ok thank you! i found that earlier but i completely misinterpreted it

Answer (score 4):

I personally would recommend creating a new [`numpy.random.RandomState`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.html) object rather than using `np.random.seed`. For example:

```
import numpy as np

rs = np.random.RandomState(0)
x = rs.randn(10)
```

will give an equivalent result to:

```
np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.randn(10)
```

However the first method is much more explicit and makes it easier to keep track of the RNG state, for example in cases where you need multiple random number generators with different internal states.